# Quantumly hard problem but classically easy

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-computer, computer

It is usually said that the quantum computer can solve classically hard problem but quantumly easy. See for example [the Preskill video](https://youtu.be/w08pSFsAZvE?t=1353).

Are there important problems of the opposite: the classical digital bit computer can solve quantumly hard problem but classically easy?

What are these kinds of problems?

[image]

Comment: "This demonstrates an important fact about quantum computers: they can do anything that a classical computer can do, and they can do so with at least the same computational complexity." https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-gates/oracles.html

Comment: I don't think there is such a problem. If by *quantumly hard* and *classically easy* you mean something which is not in the class BQP (problems solvable by polynomial-time quantum Turing machine) and is in either the class P or the class BPP (problems solvable by polynomial-time probabilistic Turing machine; note that P is within BPP), then it would be contradictory to the fact that BPP is contained within BQP.

Comment: While purely theoretically I completely agree with the other comments, I think it's also worth saying that quantum computers with $N$ qubits will very likely always be (much) more expensive than classical computers with $N$ bits, because of the need to reduce decoherence. (And of course, at today's level of technology, the number of qubits on the world's largest quantum computer is orders and orders of magnitude smaller than the number of bits on a classical laptop). So quantum computers are unlikely to *replace* classical computers, even if theoretically they can solve the same problems.

Comment: In other words, even if classical computers don't have a *computational complexity* edge over quantum computers, they do have a massive *ease of implementation in the real world* edge. So you shouldn't conclude that quantum computers are going to be at least as good or better than classical computers in practical situations.